# Difference between "binding" and "attaching" in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Android beginner here. I've seen both the term "attach" and "bind" in many places in the documentation, and they both sound very similar. What is the difference?

I know the `fragment` class has an `onAttach` method that is called early in their lifecycle. What does this do, exactly? Does it add a reference to the `fragment` in the original activity's context, or does it simply tell the O.S. that these two objects are related? Where would the O.S. store this information?

And what is the difference between "Attach" and "Bind." I know services have an `onBind` method but some components, for example `listAdapter`, also need to be "bound" somehow. What does this do, exactly, in both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my perspective, `bind` is more often used for 'joining' two separate entities (or instance) in which the two shares or manipulates a common data set. A service has `onBind()` because it will - or is - manipulate a particular set of data which will going to be passed back to its corresponding activity/fragment that starts it. Same goes for a `ListAdapter`, an adapter "binds" data to a view so that it can be displayed in a particular manner  depending on how said adapter was built.

On the other hand, `attach` simply means.. well.. *attach*. Why a fragment is said to be "attached" rather than "bound" (and has `onAttach()` rather than `onBind()`) is that a fragment doesn't necessarily share the same set of data with its containing activity. It can be of a completely different use and not strictly related with its housing activity in the term of data being used or manipulated. This is supported by the fact that reusability was one of the main reason behind the creation of `Fragment` in Android.

But of course this is just an opinion; this is how I percieve it to be. Despite that I am quite certain of this (it's logical for me) the *real* reason behind those naming lies still in the hands of its author. Until they decided to actually let people know, I don't think that there will be an explanation that could be considered as the actual truth.